# How to import existing files into IntelliJ 10 IDE?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have used Eclipse before. I changed to IntelliJ. Now I am wondering how to import existing files into IntelliJ 10 IDE. In Eclipse I was used to just drag the directory into the `src` folder, but I cannot do it here.

Comment: do you mean, to import a project in intellij? Are you using maven (intellij has an very good integration with maven)

Comment: no,I mean just import some java files into src folder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IDEA doesn't have such feature, you either set up a project on top of the existing sources or you copy files to the existing project externally, using Finder or your favorite file manager.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can tell IDEA to open a project and when you get prompted with the file explorer you select the eclipse project file. IDEA will then create it's own specific project files and setup the classpath for you. It's pretty nifty.